# C# simple divide problem

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
 double result = 60 / 23;
```

In my program, the result is 2, but correct is 2,608695652173913. Where is problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use any of the following all will give **2.60869565217391**:

```
 double result = 60 / 23d;  
 double result = 60d / 23;  
 double result = 60d/ 23d;  
 double result = 60.0 / 23.0;
```

**But**

```
double result = 60 / 23;  //give 2
```

**Explanation:**

if **any of the number is double** it will give a double

---

**EDIT:**

**Documentation**

> The evaluation of the expression is performed according to the following rules:
>
> - If one of the floating-point types is double, the expression evaluates to double (or bool in the case of relational or Boolean expressions).
> - If there is no double type in the expression, it evaluates to float (or bool in the case of relational or Boolean expressions).

Answer (score 51):

60 and 23 are integer literals so you are doing integer division and then assigning to a double.  The result of the integer division is 2.

Try

```
double result = 60.0 / 23.0;
```

Or equivalently

```
double result = 60d / 23d;
```

Where the d suffix informs the complier that you meant to write a double literal.

Comment: I think this should be marked as answer, since the explenation marked as answer copied this..

Comment: @ Nick, i did not copied it if you think so i am updating it

Answer (score 9):

It will work

```
double result = (double)60 / (double) 23;
```

Or equivalently

```
double result = (double)60 /  23;
```

Comment: Eventhough the compiler will propably optimize it away, this code produces the behaviour: Take the integer 60, then cast it to a double. Take the integer 23, then cast it to a double. Divide the results of both casts. It's better to use double values in the first place (as in the answer of James Gaunt)

Comment: But this is only(?) way if you are not dealing with fixed numbers, but with integer variables.

Comment: This way you are really hoping that the complier will optimise away the cast.  As it's written it just introduces extra work by performing a runtime type cast.  It works - but it's a bit ugly.

Comment: @Jens: Yes, if you need to work with variables that are integers but need to have floating point results the only solution is to cast them. But if you have some kind of constant then you should use the proper type for it.

Answer (score 3):

(double) 60 / 23

Comment: It actually would - the type cast (double) is higher precedence than the divide, and a double divided by an int results in a double. But 60.0/23.0 is clearer and thus a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't used C# for a while, but you are dividing two integers, which as far as I remember makes the result an integer as well.

You can force your number literals to be doubles by adding the letter "d", likes this:

```
double result = 60d / 23d;
```

Comment: OK, this works. But how to do it, if I have this: double result = 60d /someList.Count;

Comment: Use a Convert function for the other operand. Eg: Convert.ToDouble(someList.Count)

Comment: double result = 60d /System.Convert.ToDouble(someList.Count);

Comment: The result should also still be a double if at least one of the operands is a double as well. You can make sure that's the case by either casting your variable(s) to double of using a double literal like shown above.

Answer (score 3):

double result = 60.0 / 23.0;

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice to correctly decorate numerals for their appropriate type. This avoids not only the bug you are experiencing, but makes the code more readable and maintainable.

```
double x = 100d;
single x = 100f;
decimal x = 100m;
```

Answer (score 1):

convert the dividend and divisor into double values, so that result is double
double res= 60d/23d;

Comment: What is the difference to the already given and accepted answer??

Answer (score 0):

To add to what has been said so far...  60/23 is an operation on two constants.  The compiler recognizes the result as a constant and pre-computes the answer.  Since the operation is on two integers, the compiler uses an integer result The integer operation of 60/23 has a result of 2; so the compiler effective creates the following code:

```
double result = 2;
```

As has been pointed out already, you need to tell the compiler not to use integers, changing one or both of the operands to non-integer will get the compiler to use a floating-point constant.