# Java int vs. Double

Tags: java, function, double, int

```
public double calc(int v1) {
return v1 / 2 + 1.5;
}


public double cald (double v) {
return v / 2 + 1.5;
}
```

Do the functions return the same result?

I would argue that they don't return the same result, as the second function would include the decimal point, where as the second function would round the number up.

Is that correct?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see? :)

Comment: @veredesmarald: he could try only 2 and 2.0, the point is to find good test cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you divide `a` by `b`  i.e `a/b`

if **both** `a` & `b` are `int` then result will be `int`
else **any or both** `a` & `b` are `double` then result will be `double`

**Edit:**

Also see my answer to this Question [Simple Divide Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162858/c-simple-divide-problem/4163426#4163426)

Answer (score 2):

They don't: [see sample on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/fTPrl), clone it and play with it.

```
System.out.println(calc(1));// gives 1.5
System.out.println(cald(1.0));// gives 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int v1 = 1;
return v1 / 2 + 1.5; // = 1.5
```

it is an integer divided by an integer more double.
Or in your case 1 / 2, that it is 0.5, but it is a division amoung ints, so will be 0, more 1.5, return 1.5.

```
double v = 1.0;
return v / 2 + 1.5; // = 2.0
```

This case, the division is between an double and an int, returning an double  of value 0.5, summing with 1.5 will return 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

They don't return the same. `/` on default is integer division if the numbers are integers, i.e., the result of `a/2` is an integer without the reminder if a is an integer. while if a is a double, then the result of this division is a double.

```
5/2 = 2
5.0/2 = 2.5
```