# Get network Download and Upload speed

Tags: c#

I try to get network Download and Upload speed:

```
NetworkInterface[] nicArr = null;
IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats = null;

private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
        interfaceStats = nicArr[selectedIndex].GetIPv4Statistics();

        long bytesReceived = interfaceStats.BytesReceived;
        long bytesSent = interfaceStats.BytesSent;

        long CurrentBytesReceived = interfaceStats.BytesReceived;
        long CurrentBytesSent = interfaceStats.BytesSent;
        lblDownload2.Text = (CurrentBytesReceived - bytesReceived).ToString();
        lblUpload2.Text = ((CurrentBytesSent - bytesSent)).ToString();
}
```

My problem is that my `Download` speed is start with `517854` and this number only raising and raising (same with `Upload` speed) and when there is no traffic this number continue to remained high instead of being zero

Comment: Read the documentation for those properties.

Comment: Store the initial values `interfaceStats.BytesReceived` and `interfaceStats.BytesSent` when your program starts and return `(interfaceStats.BytesReceived-initialBytesReceived) / 1024;`

Comment: Not related to your problem but you need to do `1024d` or you will get integer division and never get any numbers after the decimal port.

Comment: What this 1024d ? can you give me an exapmle ?

Comment: `return (interfaceStats.BytesSent) / 1024;` because `BytesSent` is a `long` and `1024` is also a `long` dividing those two will return a `long` and it truncates the result. So if you had `1023` for `BytesSent` doing `1023 / 1024` returns `0`. However doing `1023 / 1024d` returns `0.9990234375`. Adding a `d` to the end of the number is a simpler way of doing `((double)1024)`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162858/c-sharp-simple-divide-problem) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those properties contain the **total** amounts sent and received, it will constantly increase.

You need to get an initial value and then on an interval poll the current value and work out the difference.

A very rough example:

```
var base_value = interfaceStats.BytesReceived;

while (true) {
    var current_value = interfaceStats.BytesReceived;
    var diff = current_value - base_value;

    Console.WriteLine(diff + " bytes/sec");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those property gives you the total bytes transferred, what you need is the [derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of that number (The rate of change).

The easiest way is just do the simple math problem

```
total2 - total1
---------------
 time2 - time1
```

So you will need two recordings then compare those two points to get the speed.

```
private long _lastBytesRecevied;
private long _lastBytesSent;
private DateTime _lastReceivedMesurement;
private DateTime _lastSentMesurement;

//This needs to be done once at the start of the class to "seed" the first value.
private Init()
{
    _lastReceivedMesurement = DateTime.UtcNow;
    _lastBytesRecevied = interfaceStats.BytesReceived;

    _lastSentMesurement = DateTime.UtcNow;
    _lastBytesSent = interfaceStats.BytesSent;
}

private double getKBDownloadSpeed()
{
    double result = (interfaceStats.BytesReceived - _lastBytesRecevied) / (DateTime.UtcNow - _lastMesurement).TotalSeconds;

    _lastReceivedMesurement = DateTime.UtcNow;
    _lastBytesRecevied = interfaceStats.BytesReceived;

    return result / 1024d;
}

private double getKBUploadSpeed()
{
    double result = (interfaceStats.BytesSent - _lastBytesSent) / (DateTime.UtcNow - _lastSentMesurement).TotalSeconds;

    _lastSentMesurement = DateTime.UtcNow;
    _lastBytesSent = interfaceStats.BytesSent;

    return result / 1024d;
}
```

Now your two functions returns the average download speed between the last time the function was called and the current call.